# How to get UITextView text from storyboard

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, uitextview, nib

I have a viewController, which has a xib for iPad and storyboard for iPhone, which I know is bad. but my previous developer made it this way. This app uses background threads to pull or send chat messages. I've successfully incorporated sending function.

Now, my problem is, whenever the program receives a chat, it gets the viewController object from the Nib, and my textView for iPhone which is made in storyboard returns (null). I tried to get that textView using storyBoard object but no result. Please help.

currently I've done this so far

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
                    conferenceViewController *conference=(conferenceViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"conference"];

                    NSLog(@"conference :%@",conference);

                    conference.receivedMessage = [NSString stringWithCString:chat->message encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
                    conference.senderDisplayName = [NSString stringWithCString:chat->displayName encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];



                    NSLog(@"chatwindow:%@",conference.chatWindow);
                    NSLog(@"chatwindow text:%@", [conference.chatWindow text]);

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{


                    if ([conference.lastPerson isEqualToString:conference.senderDisplayName]) {
                        [conference.chatWindow setText:[conference.chatWindow.text stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n%@",conference.receivedMessage]]];
                    } else {
                        [conference.chatWindow setText:[conference.chatWindow.text stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n%@: \n%@",conference.senderDisplayName,conference.receivedMessage]]];
                    }

                    conference.lastPerson = conference.senderDisplayName;
                    [conference.chatWindow scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange([conference.chatWindow.text length], 0)];
                });
```

Comment: I would check to make sure you storyboard name is correct and make sure it has a view controller that is a class of conferenceViewController. Does the first line of code return the storyboard?

Comment: @JustinHolman thanks for the reply. but i resolved it using the NotificationCenter.